Загрузка проекта на PyPi
Сделал простой проект, и собираюсь выкладывать на PyPi. Вот что делал:

Установил все модули: pip install twine build setuptools
"Собрал" проект: python3 -m build
Загружаю для начала на test PyPi: python3 -m twine upload -r testpypi dist/*,

На 3-м этапе сталкиваюсь с проблемой: по гайду, должно было вывести "username:", но почему-то выводит это: Enter your API token:. Что писать в это поле? Аккаунт на PyPi зарегистрирован и сделана 2-х кратная ацетификация.

Вот кому нужно что мне помогло:

Создание файла .pypirc в корне проекта ($HOME/.pypirc)
Использование команды python3 -m twine upload -r testpypi dist/* с "флажком" --verbose; итоговая команда: python3 -m twine upload -r testpypi dist/* --verbose. Так Вы сможете найти конкретную ошибку, у меня была "Название NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT слишком похоже к существующему проекту (перевел дословно)


Если чужой ответ вам не помог, то лучше свой отметить принятым. Но это на ваше усмотрение.

Сначала раскройте меню, нажав на username вашего аккаунта в правом верхнем углу. Перейдите в "Настройки учётной записи"

Затем пролистайте вниз, пока не увидите "API-токены". Сгенерируйте новый и после этого используйте полученный токен для выпуска проекта.


PS D:\ProgrammingProjects\Python\BetterInput> python3 -m twine upload -r testpypi dist/* Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ Enter your API token:  Uploading BetterInput-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl 100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.2/10.2 kB • 00:00 • ? WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details. ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/Forbidden
Выводит данную ошибку. Пробовал вводить и имя и сам токен с "префиксом" pypi-

Попробовал "вручную" указать все данные:
python3 -m twine upload -u my_username -p my_password --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*, но все равно: эта ошибка

@Funsy проверьте, что токен для test.pypi.org генерируете на https://test.pypi.org. Также при аутентификации по токену нужно пустое имя указывать (или не указывать вообще), токен передавать вместо пароля (по поводу последнего не на 100% уверен, но вроде бы так было).

Да, генерировал на test.pypi.org. Сделал все как Вы сказали:
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ Bad Request
